# Upgrading mysql caused broken packages

Tags: apt, package-management, mysql, aptitude

I have Debian Jessie, and MySQL 5.6 from the [MySQL Debian repository](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/repo/apt/). This installation installes an apt `sources.list.d` entry that after `sudo apt-get install mysql-community-server`, it asks whether I want to install MySQL 5.6 or 5.7.

This setup has been working for months.

Today I did a `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade`. It caused a conflict. The following is what I'm getting:

```
Duplicate sources.list entry http://repo.mysql.com/apt//debian/ jessie/mysql-5.6 amd64 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/repo.mysql.com_apt__debian_dists_jessie_mysql-5.6_binary-amd64_Packages)
Duplicate sources.list entry http://repo.mysql.com/apt//debian/ jessie/mysql-5.6 i386 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/repo.mysql.com_apt__debian_dists_jessie_mysql-5.6_binary-i386_Packages)
You may want to run apt-get update to correct these problems
Reading package lists... Done
W: Duplicate sources.list entry http://repo.mysql.com/apt//debian/ jessie/mysql-5.6 amd64 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/repo.mysql.com_apt__debian_dists_jessie_mysql-5.6_binary-amd64_Packages)
W: Duplicate sources.list entry http://repo.mysql.com/apt//debian/ jessie/mysql-5.6 i386 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/repo.mysql.com_apt__debian_dists_jessie_mysql-5.6_binary-i386_Packages)
W: You may want to run apt-get update to correct these problems
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libmysqlclient18 : Depends: mysql-common (>= 5.7.5-m15-2debian8)
 mysql-community-client : Depends: mysql-common (= 5.7.12-1debian8)
E: Broken packages
```

It's weird because I didn't choose MySQL 5.7! Why is it asking for it. Looking at the MySQL apt entry in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/mysql.list`, it shows up to be:

```
### THIS FILE IS AUTOMATICALLY CONFIGURED ###
# You may comment out entries below, but any other modifications may be lost.
# Use command 'dpkg-reconfigure mysql-apt-config' as root for modifications.
deb http://repo.mysql.com/apt//debian/ jessie mysql-apt-config
deb http://repo.mysql.com/apt//debian/ jessie mysql-5.6
deb http://repo.mysql.com/apt//debian/ jessie mysql-5.6 mysql-5.7-dmr mysql-5.7 connector-python-2.0 connector-python-2.1 router-2.0 mysql-utilities-1.5 mysql-tools    
deb-src http://repo.mysql.com/apt//debian/ jessie mysql-5.6
```

And I don't understand where the 5.7 comes from and whether it's correct to see it there.

I also tried to fix the apt entry with `sudo dpkg-reconfigure mysql-apt-config`, but didn't help.

Any ideas how to fix these broken packages?

---

**EDIT:**

Requested in comments:

```
$ apt-cache policy mysql-common libmysqlclient18 mysql-community-client
mysql-common:
  Installed: 5.6.30-1debian8
  Candidate: 5.7.12-1debian8
  Version table:
     5.7.12-1debian8 0
        500 http://repo.mysql.com/apt//debian/ jessie/mysql-5.7 amd64 Packages
     5.7.8-rc-1debian8 0
        500 http://repo.mysql.com/apt//debian/ jessie/mysql-5.7-dmr amd64 Packages
 *** 5.6.30-1debian8 0
        500 http://repo.mysql.com/apt//debian/ jessie/mysql-5.6 amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     5.5.47-0+deb8u1 0
        500 http://security.debian.org/ jessie/updates/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://httpredir.debian.org/debian/ stable/main amd64 Packages
libmysqlclient18:
  Installed: 5.6.30-1debian8
  Candidate: 5.7.5-m15-2debian8
  Version table:
     5.7.5-m15-2debian8 0
        500 http://repo.mysql.com/apt//debian/ jessie/mysql-5.7-dmr amd64 Packages
 *** 5.6.30-1debian8 0
        500 http://repo.mysql.com/apt//debian/ jessie/mysql-5.6 amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     5.5.47-0+deb8u1 0
        500 http://security.debian.org/ jessie/updates/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://httpredir.debian.org/debian/ stable/main amd64 Packages
mysql-community-client:
  Installed: 5.6.30-1debian8
  Candidate: 5.7.12-1debian8
  Version table:
     5.7.12-1debian8 0
        500 http://repo.mysql.com/apt//debian/ jessie/mysql-5.7 amd64 Packages
     5.7.8-rc-1debian8 0
        500 http://repo.mysql.com/apt//debian/ jessie/mysql-5.7-dmr amd64 Packages
 *** 5.6.30-1debian8 0
        500 http://repo.mysql.com/apt//debian/ jessie/mysql-5.6 amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
W: Duplicate sources.list entry http://repo.mysql.com/apt//debian/ jessie/mysql-5.6 amd64 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/repo.mysql.com_apt__debian_dists_jessie_mysql-5.6_binary-amd64_Packages)
W: Duplicate sources.list entry http://repo.mysql.com/apt//debian/ jessie/mysql-5.6 i386 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/repo.mysql.com_apt__debian_dists_jessie_mysql-5.6_binary-i386_Packages)
W: You may want to run apt-get update to correct these problems
```

Comment: Output of `apt-cache policy mysql-common libmysqlclient18 mysql-community-client` to start with.

Comment: The line `deb http://repo.mysql.com/apt//debian/ jessie mysql-5.6 mysql-5.7-dmr mysql-5.7 connector-python-2.0 connector-python-2.1 router-2.0 mysql-utilities-1.5 mysql-tools`. Is weird. Do you really have it in there like that?

Comment: @FaheemMitha Thank you for your response. I did add the command you asked for. Yes, that line is very weird. Actually if I remove it, the problem goes away. But I'm not depending on that because this has to be managed by the MySQL people... changing this file will not remain permanently.

Comment: Adding files under `/etc/sources.list.d` as part of the package is broken behavior, imo. I suggest you file a bug, and tell the maintainers what difficulties you are facing. An alternative is to backport the Debian packages from unstable.

Comment: @FaheemMitha Actually many organizations use this method, including gitlab. Thanks for the advice. I'll file a report if this doesn't get fixed within 2 days.

Comment: @FaheemMitha They responded.

Comment: Ok, good. I still think that installing sources.list entries as part of a package is a misfeature. But good on you for taking the initiative.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The guys from MySQL replied and declared this as a bug. The following is their message:

> Hi,
>
> Thanks for the report. This seems to be a bug in the new version of
>   mysql-apt-config.  In your /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mysql.list file,
>   the line:  `deb http://repo.mysql.com/apt//debian/ jessie mysql-5.6
>   mysql-5.7-dmr mysql-5.7 connector-python-2.0 connector-python-2.1
>   router-2.0 mysql-utilities-1.5 mysql-tools` Should not contain the
>   entries `mysql-5.6 mysql-5.7-dmr mysql-5.7` As a workaround you can
>   remove these entries from that line, until we can fix the bug.